# PHP explode array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get random values out of an array and then break them down further, here's the initial code:

```
$in = array('foo_1|bar_1', 'foo_2|bar_2','foo_3|bar_3','foo_4|bar_4','foo_5|bar_5' );
$rand = array_rand($in, 3);

$in[$rand[0]]; //foo_1|bar_1
$in[$rand[1]]; //foo_3|bar_3
$in[$rand[2]]; //foo_5|bar_5
```

What I want is same as above but with each 'foo' and 'bar' individually accessible via their own key, something like this:

```
$in[$rand[0]][0] //foo_1
$in[$rand[0]][1] //bar_1

$in[$rand[1]][0] //foo_3
$in[$rand[1]][1] //bar_3

$in[$rand[2]][0] //foo_5
$in[$rand[2]][1] //bar_5
```

I've tried exploding $rand via a foreach loop but I'm obviously making some n00b error:

```
foreach($rand as $r){
$result = explode("|", $r);  
$array = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
$in = array('foo_1|bar_1', 'foo_2|bar_2','foo_3|bar_3','foo_4|bar_4','foo_5|bar_5' );

foreach($in as &$r){
  $r = explode("|", $r);  
}

$rand = array_rand($in, 3);
```

That modifies `$in` "on the fly", so it contains the nested array structure you're looking for.

Now...

```
$in[$rand[0]][0] //foo_1
$in[$rand[0]][1] //bar_1

$in[$rand[1]][0] //foo_3
$in[$rand[1]][1] //bar_3

$in[$rand[2]][0] //foo_5
$in[$rand[2]][1] //bar_5
```

I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You were close:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($in as $r)
    $array[] = explode("|", $r);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($rand as $r){
  $result = explode("|", $r);  
  array_push($array, $result);
}
```