# save form field value as array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form field called `$_POST['hidden-tags']`

It has values entered in as follows

```
cars, vans, bikes, trains,
```

I on post im trying to split the values and save them into an array and then compare that array with another I have and only display the values that are different.  I know the $arr1 has values as I have tested the data.

the code I have so far is

```
  $arr1;

  $arr2 = array();

foreach($_POST['hidden-tags'] as $value){
$arr2[] = explode(",",$value);  
}

print_r($arr2);

   // $tmp = array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2);
     //  echo $tmp;
```

parts of which I found here on stack
[PHP explode array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697008/php-explode-array)

As you can see I have the final bit commented out.  This is so I can see the array values.  If I echo the $arr2 all I see on screen is

> Array()

even though I have entered cars, bikes, vans.  I have not got as far as comparing the two array yet and displaying the $tmp variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$_POST['hidden-tags']` a text input field? If so, you don't need to run a `foreach` on it to split it into an array. Just explode it and compare the generated array with the one you already have.

Comment: will do.  Just waiting as it wont let me accept straight away

Answer (score 0):

I don't think $_POST['hidden-tags'] is an array, but a string you want to split.

Also I think you don't want to save the result of the split action on your POST variable in the next index of $arr2, because split will return an array and this way you will have an array in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $arr1;

    $arr2 = array();

    $arr2[] = explode(",",$_POST['hidden-tags']);  

    print_r($arr2);

    $tmp = array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2);
    echo $tmp;
```